# Can't login to Ubuntu in virtual machine

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-systems, linux-device-driver, open-source

When I updated the system, and then I restarted the machine, I don't know why it's showing this picture:
[image] Can someone solve this problem?

I tried to restart the machine again and again, but its still not working,

Comment: Looking at the errors, the machine is not starting properly (not a login error). Try booting in recovery mode:   https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/use-recovery-mode   ....  Try spinning up a new Ubuntu machine and see if that works. I have Ubuntu VMs in both VMware and Hyper-V and they work fine.

Comment: these tags are awful.  only the "linux" tag seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

Replicate what you would do with a standard PC:

1. Find a copy of a "Live disk", e.g. the install media for Ubuntu,
2. Make both the "root fs" AND
   the install media
   available for use in one single VM
3. boot the install media in "Try Ubuntu"-mode.
4. Use normal means to try repair your root fs
   *(e.g. run fsck or install Testdisk and run it)*